# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (32,256,256,3) into shape (32)

Tags: python, tf.keras

I am trying to get predictions in this loop:

```
for i in img:
    img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(i)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

    print("Predictions: " + predictions)

    print(
        "This image most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
            .format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score))
    )
```

And I also have the following code:

```
batch_size = 32
img_height = 180
img_width = 180

# Create a dataset
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    img_folder,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size
)
```

When the shape is getting accessed it's giving me the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "#", line 134, in <module>
    img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(i)
  File "#", line 228, in img_to_array
    return image.img_to_array(img, data_format=data_format, **kwargs)
  File "#", line 309, in img_to_array
    x = np.asarray(img, dtype=dtype)
  File "#", line 83, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (32,256,256,3) into shape (32)
```

Comment: Can you improve your question to include the code you're trying to run i.e. in the correct order, imports on so on? You'll stand a better chance of getting help if you include the module you've import and code which will actually run and this will make your questions useful to others with a similar problem. Also you've modified the stack trace to remove useful information. The error is telling you that you're trying to fit a round peg in a square whole. You probably have a list of multidimensional objects and only need the list, or 1 dimension for your objects.

Comment: Here's guidance on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)